# Checkboxes, PHP and MySQL performance and maintenance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, checkbox

Let say I have a MySQL database with a user table like this:

```
|ID| Name| email       |...
|1 | John| john@doe.com|...
```

I will have a php page where the user will choose with help of checkboxes, between different options in two independent interest areas. For this example lets say: favorite fruit and cars.

Fruits: Apple, Lemon, Pear, Banana.
Cars: Ferrari, Mercedes, Volvo, BMW.

Now I have two possibilities:

1.) Creating a column for each fruit and each car associated to each user, something like this:

```
|ID| Name| email       |apple | lemon | pear | banana | ferrari | mercedes | volvo | BMW |
|1 | John| john@doe.com| 1    | 1     | 0    | 1      | 0       | 1        |  0    | 1   |
```

2) Creating two new tables called: fruits and cars.

```
|ID| Name  |
| 1| Apple |
| 2| Lemon |
| 3| Pear  |
| 4| Banana|

|ID| Name     |
| 1| Ferrari  |
| 2| Mercedes |
| 3| Volvo    |
| 4| BMW      |
```

Then creating a relational table called user_fruit and another called user_cars. E.g:

```
|ID_user| ID_fruit |
| 1     | 1        |
| 1     | 2        |
| 1     | 4        |
```

(Note that fruit id 3, Pear does not appear as it not selected --> 0)

```
|ID_user| ID_car   |
| 1     | 2        |
| 1     | 4        |
```

**Question:**
I don't know which approach is better? The first one is easy at first hand, but once the options grow, the table will have to many *tinyint* columns.
The second one is more difficult at the beginning with all the relations, but is easier to maintain, except when a user uncheck one option, that I don't feel very comfortable deleting rows by php, specially on index based tables.

I don't know if someone has faced some similar task and can give me some suggestions.

I don't really need any code example, as I know how to develop both options, is more a performance and maintenance approach that I'm looking for.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely the second approach.  Have a look at [database normalization](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/283878). As you have noted, in your first approach, you will end up with a table with many "null" values, and difficult to modify later on.

Comment: Thanks, the fear I have is when a user unselects one of their options, I need to delete the complete row in the relation table, right?
Or is there any other way I'm missing?

Comment: Likely, but have a look at the term "cascade" as it relates to MySQL table declaration.  "on delete cascade..."

Answer (score 1):

Since i hated having multiple "only-10-entries" tables, i just decided to code the ID

```
|ID    | Name     |
| 1001 | Ferrari  |
| 1002 | Mercedes |
| 1003 | Volvo    |
| 1004 | BMW      |
| 2001 | Apple    |
| 2002 | Lemon    |
| 2003 | Pear     |
| 2004 | Banana   |
```

Then the code "knows" that a 2xxx is a fruit, a 1xxx is a car, etc. You could even have a id-filter table to lessen the burden

```
|ID    | Family  |
| 1000 | Cars    |
| 2000 | Fruits  |
```

This reduce the big JOIN ... JOIN ... JOIN statement when you have tremendous amount of little "options" table. It is nice performance-wise, at the cost of bigger ID space requirement (SMALLINT instead of TINYINT)

Not really database-pro but mistake-safe and you can split the table anytime.

Comment: Hmm! Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Second one is best and professional way with a foreign key on both tables.In that way you can avoid from null values.

Answer (score 0):

In the first possible way,

```
|ID| Name| email       |apple | lemon | pear | banana | ferrari | mercedes | volvo | BMW |
|1 | John| john@doe.com| 1    | 1     | 0    | 1      | 0       | 1        |  0    | 1   |
```

you will have to read only one row and then you can grab the data while in the other way you reading multiple tables and multiple row. Further there is another concept for this kind of scenario called data duplication - what ever the approach you are using tables / data has to be normalize. You can read about [this with this link](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/normalization).

Hope this will help for your decision. Cheers